# Report builder 3.0 count with where clause

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder, reportbuilder3.0

For one of our reports I'm trying to get a count of rows that have the column Canceled with value 1. In the past I used the solution I found on Stackoverflow to use the Sum function with IIF, i.e.

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!Canceled.Value="True", 1, 0))
```

But now my source data has multiple rows for one booking_id so I need to add a distinct on that column. In SQL I could easily do

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(booking_id)) FROM Booking WHERE Canceled=1
```

But I can't figure out how to get the same behaviour in Report Builder 3.0. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this in the report.  I would just do it in SQL.

Comment: If the datasource is a sql query, I agree with Tab - just do it in sql - let us know if you need help with that or if your not using a query as your datasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this in T-SQL, if possible, as suggested in the comments is not a bad idea, but you can do this in the report with an expression like:

```
=CountDistinct(IIf(Fields!Canceled.Value = 1, Fields!booking_id.Value, Nothing))
```

`CountDistinct` will ignore `Nothing` (i.e. Null) records, so you can apply a `CountDistinct` to an `IIf` expression that returns `booking_id` or `Nothing` based on `Canceled`.

Comment: @Sander, did this help at all?